# How do I use prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to learn how to use prototype in javascript, and I was hoping someone could explain the following to me.

Lets say I have a object with a prototype looking like this:

```
function Calc(sumOne, sumTwo) {
    this.sumOne = sumOne;
    this.sumTwo = sumTwo;
}

Calc.prototype.add = function() {
    var sum = this.sumOne + this.sumTwo;
    return sum;
}
```

Then lets say these objects are stored in an array when they where created like this.

```
var numbers = [];

numbers.push(new Calc(1, 2));
numbers.push(new Calc(3, 4));
numbers.push(new Calc(5, 6));
```

This would result in an array looking something like this

```
numbers = [{sumOne: 1, sumTwo: 2}, {sumOne: 3, sumTwo: 4}, {sumOne: 5, sumTwo: 6}];
```

If I now would like to run the prototype on these objects to get the result (3, 7 and 11). How would I do this?

Comment: Iterate over the array and call the `add` method of those objects?

Comment: If you want to learn more about what exactly "prototype" is, I suggest to read [You Don't Know JS - Prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md). You might also find the articles on MDN helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: @FelixKling, wow, my next reading material is going to be 'You Don't Know JS'. Thanks for the link

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Yep, it's pretty good :)

Answer (score 1):

For each `Calc` instance in the array, call `.add()` on it.

```
numbers.map(function(calc) {
  return calc.add();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over them and call the prototype method

```js
function Calc(sumOne, sumTwo) {
  this.sumOne = sumOne;
  this.sumTwo = sumTwo;
}

Calc.prototype.add = function() {
  var sum = this.sumOne + this.sumTwo;
  return sum;
}


var numbers = [];

numbers.push(new Calc(1, 2));
numbers.push(new Calc(3, 4));
numbers.push(new Calc(5, 6));


numbers.forEach(function(calcObject, index) {
  numbers[index] = calcObject.add();

});
console.log(numbers)
```